# Why Controller names are plural but application_controller is itself a singular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Why Controller names are plural but application_controller is itself a singular.

I was just curious when i scaffold a person and rails generated a people_controller for it, I was impressed but then I saw application_controller and it is singular. Does it has an explanation or it is as it is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails is full of conventions and plural names for controllers is simply one of those conventions. It is so Rails can locate the appropriate controller when you put `resources :books` in your `routes.rb`

You can override the convention and specify the controller explicitly, `resources :books, controller: "library"`. In this case, Rails will look for `LibraryController`.

With `ApplicationController`, you don't call it directly and Rails doesn't need to do this lookup and so it can be named whatever. You can rename it, for example.

Comment: "there's just one application" - that one isn't as clear cut as it seems. When you use the `resource` macro it will use the plural form instead of singular. #1 expains it better, its a base class and does not correspond to actual resources.

Comment: @max: yeah, I took out the first part entirely. The other part is better explanation, I think.